# Can you pass a cookie to the URL used in a Microsoft Bot SigninCard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, microsoft-teams

My aim (if possible) is to pass information via the use of cookies to a URL that is opened as part of a SigninCard that I use in my Bot code. The channel that I'm using this bot for is "MS Teams" although I have been testing it for "Web Chat" as well. So this is what I currently have,

```
Uri endPoint = new Uri(aUrl);
var signinCard = new SigninCard
            {
                Text = "Test Sign-in Card",
                Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Sign-in", value: endPoint) },
            };
```

A card with a sign in button will appear, which after clicking on will open the endpoint Url in the default web browser.

Its easy enough to add parameters to the URL, which I can then pick up in the browser but I would rather pass this information as a cookie so that the URL is left alone. Is this possible to do within a SigninCard?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to send the signin information to a URL (using cookies)? And what info are you looking to send?

Comment: I just wanted send information like the conversation id and user id, which would be taken from the context of the bot code. Like I said easy to send as a parameter in the url, but I want to avoid using this method and see if its possible with cookies instead.

Comment: Which channel is this for, Web Chat (I'm guessing)?

Comment: The channel is actually "MS Teams". I'll amend my question to include this.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to pass information appending cookies to the sign URL. Instead, you can get saved in conversation reference please have a look at [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/168fc60096bc2e4f494b18614a430403b700bfd7/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L18) sample.

Comment: @PradeepPatel, Did you get it working?

Comment: @Mallipriya-MSFT Sorry no I wasn't able to get this working in the end even after looking at your example as Im not sure what I was meant to take from it

Comment: @PradeepPatel - Sign in card support only  two actions: signin and openUrl. You can pass the info in URL. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in card support only two actions: signin and openUrl. You can pass the info in URL. This is by design